# Is there a way to read files from google cloud storage bucket using ConfigFactory.?

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, typesafe-config

I have to read configs from local path(for unit test) and from gcs bucket when running from dataproc cluster. The code I have written is:

```
val appConf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(pathToFile))
appConf.getConfigList("params")
```

This code is working fine when reading from local path like `/tmp/dir/file.conf`

But when passing path as `gs://bucket/folder/file.conf`
I am getting error:
No configuration setting found for key 'params'.
Is there a common way to read config from both local and gs bucket.?
Or Is there any other way to do it in some common way.?

Thanks

Comment: Extend the File class and implement the Cloud Storage logic in it. There is nothing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous comment of a community member:

> Extend the File class and implement the Cloud Storage logic in it. There is nothing out of the box.